# How to suppress a specific warning sent by cron daemon to email?

Tags: bash, centos, cron

**DEMONSTRATION** (OR STRAIGHT TO **THE REAL QUESTION** SECTION)

I have a lynis script that I use to scan my server. This script is not important to demonstrate but here is the script anyway: https://gitlab.com/sofibox/maxicron/-/blob/master/usr/local/maxicron/lynis/maxinis

This script runs perfectly and doesn't output any errors when running it manually like this through terminal:

```
./maxinis manual --cronjob
```

I also will receive an email about the scan

But, when I run this script via cronjob at specific time like this:

```
06 21 * * *     root    /usr/local/maxicron/lynis/maxinis cron --cronjob > /dev/null
```

It also run perfectly, send an email but I got an extra email from **Cron Daemon** with 3 warning outputs like this:

[image: Cron Daemon Email]

**THE REAL QUESTION IS HERE:**

My question is, based on the **3** warning messages from the picture above, I got cron daemon email warning. How do I suppress **the second line** of the warning and keep the rest output sent by Cron Daemon ?

The second line of the output is:

```
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

I tried using this `grep -v` method like this in the crontab but doesn't seems to work:

```
06 21 * * *     root    /usr/local/maxicron/lynis/maxinis cron --cronjob > /dev/null | grep -v '# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `grep` isn't working is that the messages are going to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so `grep` is never seeing them.  That's why you're getting an email even after sending `stdout` to `/dev/null`.  You can filter `stderr` like this:

```
somecommand > /dev/null 2>( grep -v 'unwanted error' 1>&2 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning about stderr and stdout. The command you given is not working. This one is working: somecommand 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep -Ev "# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them|another-output"

Comment: the `2>( )` syntax may need a newer version of `bash` than you have installed.  If you're okay with `stderr` being shunted into `stdout`, your alternative method works nicely.

Comment: thank you so much for the best explanation here.